# Using the TYPO3 crop function for cs_seo social media images

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I am using TYPO3 7LTS with Ext:cs_seo and want to crop the social media images. Unfortunately my approach via `file:current:crop` doesn't work:

```
page.meta {
    twitter:image.stdWrap.typolink {
        parameter.stdWrap {
            cObject.file >
            cObject.file {
                import {
                    preUserFunc = Clickstorm\CsSeo\UserFunc\HeaderData->getSocialMediaImage
                    preUserFunc.field = twitter_image
                    ifEmpty.data = path:{$plugin.tx_csseo.social.twitter.defaultImage} // path:{$plugin.tx_csseo.social.defaultImage}
                }
                crop.data = file:current:crop
                height < plugin.tx_csseo.social.twitter.image.height
                width < plugin.tx_csseo.social.twitter.image.width
            }
        }
    }

    og:image.stdWrap.typolink {
        parameter.stdWrap {
            cObject.file >
            cObject.file {
                import {
                    preUserFunc = Clickstorm\CsSeo\UserFunc\HeaderData->getSocialMediaImage
                    preUserFunc.field = og_image
                    ifEmpty.data = path:{$plugin.tx_csseo.social.defaultImage}
                }
                crop.data = file:current:crop
                height = {$plugin.tx_csseo.social.openGraph.image.height}
                width = {$plugin.tx_csseo.social.openGraph.image.width}

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Has somebody a clue, how I can fix it?

Thank you in advance
Bertram

Answer (score 0):

You should either get rid of the line that removes the file settings completely and disable the settings within the file section.

So the bad line IMHO should be:

```
cObject.file >
```

Since this destroys the rest of the setup.

Comment: Hi Jo,

thank you for the hint and excuse my late answer. Unfortunately deleting the the line `cObject.file >` does not change anything. :/

Comment: So is there anything within page.meta.twitter:image.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.stdWrap.cObject ? Because if not, trying to change it woudn't make much sense.

Comment: To be honest, the typoscript crops the height and width. But not the selected crop area. It crops from the center of an image.